# Расставить/убрать знаки препинания. "кроме", "как". деепричастные обороты

Tags: пунктуация

Порой у нас нет денег, потому что она спускает все в клубах или магазинах, но даже в таком случае правила остаются неизменными: дома всегда должен быть приготовленный мной ужин из того, что есть.

Сколько еще таких неумех как я, жаждущих того, чего, по их же мнению, им никогда не достичь?

В любом случае мне не понять всех тех, кто отчаянно хватается за свою никчемную жизнь, ждет не дождется финала, но при этом оттягивает его, как только может.

Несмотря на то, что я так сильно хочу тебя увидеть, мне не трудно сдерживать себя, строя глазки и недотрогу.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки правильно расставлены, кроме отсутствия запятой перед "как" (второй абзац) — там сравнительный оборот.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/32385)

Comment: @behemothus Чего это не является? Нужно знаки проверить. Кстати, знаки тут расставлены автором вопроса. В самом задании больше знаков пропущено. "Но можем проверить уже выполненные вами" [задания] — со справки.

Comment: Вас не смущает, что вопрос Aimi не по адресу? «В самом задании» — это о чём слова?

Comment: @shampar Нашёл в интернете это задание. А тут знаки расставлены. Почему не по адресу, если сюда можно давать на проверку выполненные домашние задания? Другое дело, что нужно в вопросе об этом сказать, чтобы его не закрыли.

Comment: Можно давать на проверку выполненные домашние задания? Наверное можно, но с оговорками: чтоб проделанная работа видна была, ну и не страницами, а точечно, конкретно по проблеме. Или нам с вами почитать нечего?

Comment: Тут она видна, так как всего лишь один знак пропущен. Да и проверяется оно очень быстро в процессе чтения.